# Can I Get CSS Image Rule in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get an css image rule, like (URL, Size) in JavaScript such as Variable.

***Example Show:***

**- HTML Right Syntax:**

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

**- CSS Right Syntax:**

```
<style>
body{
background: url('a.png');
background-image-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

**JS Error Syntax:**

```
    <script>
      function GetImgVar(){
       var imgsrc = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
         document.getElementById('mydiv').style.backgroundImage=imgsrc;
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: You should be setting `style.backgroundImage` to the string `"url('"+imgsrc+"')"`

Comment: __`Element.style.PROPERTY`__ reads only inline styles...

Comment: I know that, but i have 2 image, one (body image background) - two (div image background), those images, i mean it's same image on the internet url, if i had an image body, why call second image as url on the internet? i want to call same image in the body background, because the body background is finally loaded on the internet. i hope understand my question, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @SchoolforDesign — Did you consider my last comment ?

Comment: No, my brother can you show me an complete example please?

Comment: @SchoolforDesign, Can you provide a fiddle to play with ?

Comment: Yes Please, I'm waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Try it:

```
<style id="stylesheet1">
body{
background: url('a.png');
background-image-size: cover;
}
</style>

<script>
var sheet = document.querySelector('#stylesheet1').sheet;

console.log(sheet.cssRules);// This will print all css rules that belongs to the body tag;

</script>
```